# Do I need UK transit visa if i am on L2

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I am travelling with my spouse and family. My spouse has valid USA(L1A) visa while my visa(L2) is expired. Do I need UK transit visa to get the connecting flight in Manchester.

Comment: I suggest running your information through [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y).

Comment: i went through that but it is not talking about if primary applicant has valid visa and dependent visa is expired than does dependent still need transit visa while primary is also traveling together?

Comment: Please edit into your question your answers to the questions the checker asked you, such as your nationality.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a transit visa, as all visas and documents must be valid to qualify for visa-free transit.